# ¿cual es la forma correcta de instanciar?

Tags: c++

Cual es la forma correcta de instanciar el item2 en el cuerpo del main, puedo hacerlo con el item1 pero no logro hacerlo cuando llamo al otro constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct fecha{                                   
    int dia;
    string mes;
    int year;
    fecha(){};
    fecha(int,string,int);
};

struct item{                                   
    string producto;
    int codigo;
    fecha ingreso;
    item(){};
    item(string,int,fecha);
};
```

Definición del segundo constructor struct fecha

```
fecha::fecha(int dia,string mes,int year){         
    this->dia=dia;
    this->mes=mes;
    this->year=year;
}
```

Definicion de 2 constructor de struct item

```
item::item(string producto,int codigo,fecha ingreso){     
    this->producto=producto;
    this->codigo=codigo;
    this->ingreso.dia=ingreso.dia;
    this->ingreso.mes=ingreso.mes;
    this->ingreso.year=ingreso.year;
}


int main(){

fecha f1(12,"noviembre",2018);
item item1("silla",3781,f1);
```

En este punto llamo al otro constructor pero evidentemente no lo hago en forma correcta.

```
item item2("mesa",3098,fecha f2(12,"diciembre",1988));    //genera error de compilacion//

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sobra `f2` simplemente: `item item2("mesa", 3098, fecha(12, "diciembre", 1988));`, intentas definir una variable en la llamada al constructor.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

1. Construir un objeto `fecha` anónimo in situ:

   ```
   item item2("mesa", 3098, {12, "diciembre" 1988});
   ```
2. Construir un objeto `fecha` explícito y anónimo in situ:

   ```
   item item2("mesa", 3098, fecha(12, "diciembre" 1988));
   ```
3. Construir un objeto `fecha` en el mismo ámbito y pasarlo a `item`:

   ```
   fecha f(12, "diciembre" 1988);
   item item2("mesa", 3098, f);
   ```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. Puedes marcar los constructores como `default` para que el compilador se encargue de darles cuerpo:

   ```
   struct fecha{                                   
       int dia;
       string mes;
       int year;
       fecha() = default;
       fecha(int,string,int);
   };
   ```

   Sería aconsejable añadir inicialización a las variables, para tener más control sobre la construcción por defecto:

   ```
   struct fecha{                                   
       int dia = 1;
       string mes = "Enero";
       int year = 1900;
       fecha() = default;
       fecha(int,string,int);
   };
   ```

   Es más ¿acaso tiene sentido construir una fecha sin datos? elimina el constructor por defecto:

   ```
   struct fecha{                                   
       int dia;
       string mes;
       int year;
       fecha(int,string,int);
   };
   ```
2. Puedes ahorrarte el `this` si usas la lista de inicialización del constructor:

   ```
   fecha::fecha(int dia,string mes,int year) :
       dia{dia}, mes{mes}, year{year}
   {         
   }
   ```

   En el contexto de la lista de inicialización, sólo puedes referirte a variables del objeto, así que no hay ambigüedad incluso con el mismo nombre.

Sigue las mismas recomendaciones para el objeto `item`.